# Notifacation timer in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angularjs as a javascript framework for my frontend,and somewhere in my code i need to show error message followed by warning message ,like this:
when user insert wrong month this message appears:

```
notification.showError("error month");
notification.showWarning("You shoud enter month between a and b");
```

How can i set time between two messages and make them disappear immediately when user press the button and appear again?
thank you

Comment: `setTimeout(() => { notification.show("You should ...") }, 1000)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your component you inject the $timeout service by adding it to the dependency list. Then you passing a function and how long until it is called.

```
$timeout(() => { notification.showWarning("You shoud enter month between a and b"); }, 1000);
```

[Angular $timeout service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)

Comment: Thank you,but is there any parameter for priority,like what come first?

Comment: The 1000 how long until the supplied function fires, in this case 1 second.